# python: Selective redirection of stdout to a file

Tags: python, stdout

I am using python's module called `dis` for analysis of bytecode. By default `dis` will send the output to the screen. I would like to re-direct the output of `dis` to a file without modifying `dis` module. The problem is, i call `dis` from within a long program after some condition is true. I will give an example!

```
class foo(object):

   def method1():
      print 'something'
      name = 6
      print name

class boo(object):

    def method1():
       print 'nothing'
       name = 10
       print name

import dis
# other statements
if foo.method1.im_func.func_code.co_code != boo.method1.im_func.func_code.co_code:
       dis.dis(method1) # would like to redirect output to a file
       dis.dis(method2)  # would like to redirect output to a file
# other statements
```

using `sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')` sends everything to a file. However there are some statments which are part of the main program i would like to see printed on the screen as the program is running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set and reset `sys.stdout` before and after calling `dis` routines:

```
sys.stdout = dis_output_file
dis.dis(method1)
dis.dis(method2)
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

`sys.__stdout__` always refers to the actual standard output of your application.

Of course, if you are using multiple threads, this approach would fail.